# Why is "justify-content: space-between" not working even after I have put the code in the container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to implement felx-[the image of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFhW6.png)box, but the justify-content:space between property is not working in the  container, I even tried to use borders, but that too is not creating any changes to the boxes. What am I doing wrong, could not figure out. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

```css
body{
    background-color: gold;
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

.img{
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-left:0;
    height:500px;
    width:1350px;
    }

 ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black; 
    overflow: hidden;
   
}

li{
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 18px 20px;
  
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
}  

 li a:hover {
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.active {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
  }

 .sb{
      margin:10px;
      padding:7px;
      text-align: left;
      position: absolute;
      right: 220px;
      padding-left:50px;
   }

  .button{
    position:absolute;
    right:100px;
    margin:10px;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    padding-top:8px;
    border-radius:3px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    color:white;
    background-color: #04AA6D;

  }

  .button:hover {
    background-color: darkorchid;
  }

  .box{
      display:flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      justify-content: space-between;
      font-weight: bolder;
      font-size: 120%;
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif
  }

  .one{
        flex-grow: 1;
        background-color: orange;
        margin-top:20px;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 50px;
        border:white;
    }
  .two{
    flex-grow: 2;
    background-color: rgb(252, 95, 95);
    margin-top:20px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 50px;
    border:black;
   

  }

  .three{
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color:orangered;
    margin-top:20px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 40px;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

       <div class="image">
        <img class="img" src="Love music.jpg">

       </div>

        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#Test">Trending</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#Click">Your-playlist</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#Test">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="log" href="#login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a class="sgp" href="#Signup">Signup</a></li>
          <form><input class="sb" type="text" placeholder="Searchbar"></form>
          <button  class="button" type="button">Search</button> 
            
        </ul>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="one">One</div>
            <div class="two">Two</div>
            <div class="three">Three</div>
          </div>

          <div class="box">
            <div class="one">One</div>
            <div class="two">Two</div>
            <div class="three">Three</div>
          </div>

          <div class="box">
            <div class="one">One</div>
            <div class="two">Two</div>
            <div class="three">Three</div>
          </div>   
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What result do you expect? What do you mean by **is not working**?

Comment: When I use justify content:space-between, it is not adding the spaces between the three boxes that I have created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set `flex-grow` property, what makes the divs take the whole free space. If you remove that, then you'll have your spaces.

```css
body{
    background-color: gold;
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

.img{
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-left:0;
    height:500px;
    width:1350px;
    }

 ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black; 
    overflow: hidden;
   
}

li{
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 18px 20px;
  
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
}  

 li a:hover {
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.active {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
  }

 .sb{
      margin:10px;
      padding:7px;
      text-align: left;
      position: absolute;
      right: 220px;
      padding-left:50px;
   }

  .button{
    position:absolute;
    right:100px;
    margin:10px;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    padding-top:8px;
    border-radius:3px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    color:white;
    background-color: #04AA6D;

  }

  .button:hover {
    background-color: darkorchid;
  }

  .box{
      display:flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      justify-content: space-between;
      font-weight: bolder;
      font-size: 120%;
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif
  }

  .one{
        background-color: orange;
        margin-top:20px;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 50px;
        border:white;
    }
  .two{
    background-color: rgb(252, 95, 95);
    margin-top:20px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 50px;
    border:black;
   

  }

  .three{
    background-color:orangered;
    margin-top:20px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 40px;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

       <div class="image">
        <img class="img" src="Love music.jpg">

       </div>

        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#Test">Trending</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#Click">Your-playlist</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#Test">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="log" href="#login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a class="sgp" href="#Signup">Signup</a></li>
          <form><input class="sb" type="text" placeholder="Searchbar"></form>
          <button  class="button" type="button">Search</button> 
            
        </ul>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="one">One</div>
            <div class="two">Two</div>
            <div class="three">Three</div>
          </div>

          <div class="box">
            <div class="one">One</div>
            <div class="two">Two</div>
            <div class="three">Three</div>
          </div>

          <div class="box">
            <div class="one">One</div>
            <div class="two">Two</div>
            <div class="three">Three</div>
          </div>   
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a container with display flex for your boxes. like below code:

```css
body {
  background-color: gold;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 120%;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif
}

.one {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: orange;
  margin-top: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 50px;
  border: white;
}

.two {
  flex-grow: 2;
  background-color: rgb(252, 95, 95);
  margin-top: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 50px;
  border: black;
}

.three {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: orangered;
  margin-top: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="one">One</div>
    <div class="two">Two</div>
    <div class="three">Three</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="one">One</div>
    <div class="two">Two</div>
    <div class="three">Three</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="one">One</div>
    <div class="two">Two</div>
    <div class="three">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

for more: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: in my code, instead of naming it a container, I have named it a box, so do I need to write it separately?  if yes, I would like to ask why. Also it is confusing if flex flow and the display works with the container that I have created and named as box, why would the justify content or the border isn't working with my container(box)?

Comment: It would not work, the program considers the box as the container, when I tried your suggested line of code, and switches to the default row view.

Comment: Read the link I added to answer! And compare the snippet code with yours again.

Answer (score 0):

You have added flex-grow property in your CSS. What it does is even the space-between property is applied the div grow its size in the ratio of 1:2:3.

So to fix your problem just remove the flex-grow property from classes "one", "two" and "Three".

[image: Here is the screen shot of how it looks after you remove the properties]